# Invoke with Chart Control is terribly slow

Tags: c#, invoke

I recently moved my program to x64 using Sockets from (I think .Net 4.0 using) COM, where I didn't even know the command "Invoke"
Now I know it all too well and it brings my program to a crawl.
I do lots of simple stuff like:

```
chart1.Series[Series1].Color = Color.White;
```

Now I need to add the `Invoke` because of Cross Threading

```
chart1.Invoke(new Action(() => chart1.Series[Series1].Color = Color.White;
```

Now the program is unusable, because its way too slow.  I run through 100's of transactions a second.
The old 32bit version worked fine, now not so much (`Invoke`).

The only thing that's changed are all the Invokes and the Sockets which work fine.

Is there any other method I can use to speed this thing up?

Can I execute `Invoke` multiple times in a "batch"?

Do I need to use `Invoke` every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's worth trying to bunch the invokes together. You don't have to call invoke separately for each control. Maybe something like this:

```
Invoke
(
    new Action
    (
        () =>
        {
            chart1.Series[Series1].Color = Color.White;
            chart2.Series[Series2].Color = Color.Blue;
        }
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks Robyn, I'll try it